# Unclear passage in integration involving Gamma functions

Tags: integration, gamma-function

I find myself in need of some advice on an integration problem.

Let $F(x,\lambda)=\Gamma(x,\lambda)/\Gamma(x)$, $x,\lambda>0$ be the Regularized Upper Incomplete Gamma Function, where $\Gamma(x,\lambda) = \int_\lambda^\infty e^{-s}s^{x-1}ds,$ and $\Gamma(x) = \int_0^\infty e^{-t}t^{x-1}dt$.

Let

(1) $m_k(\lambda)=\int_0^\infty x^k d F(x,\lambda)$

In some notes I'm reading I found the following identity

(2) $m_k(\lambda)=k \int_0^\infty x^{k-1} [1-F(x,\lambda)]dx$.

Any idea on how to go from (1) to (2)? Maybe I'm missing something or there's a typo somewhere I can't spot. Note: based on this result, another one is derived, that actually seems correct (although based on empirical evidence only).

Comment: integration by parts

Comment: Didn't think of that! I'll try, thanks!

Comment: @tired Ok, the suggestion is certainly the correct one, but I still can't seem to find a solution past the first step of integration by parts.. either I go back, or I get stuck with a much more complicated integral.. what am I doing wrong? The choice of $v=F(x)$ and $u=x^k$ doesn't help me..